# Is there a punishment for diving in Soccer?

Tags: rules, football

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What actions are taken by FIFA/UEFA against what's known as filming or diving](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1010/what-actions-are-taken-by-fifa-uefa-against-whats-known-as-filming-or-diving)

When I think of European soccer I think of [diving](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LC-H2wXK4T4&feature=related). Is there any punishment for diving/embellishment in Soccer (football)? Either a card, fine, or suspension?

Coming from a hockey background, I know if you [dive](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bK2EJhuHsl0) in hockey and the refs catch you, you can receive a two minute penalty for rule [64.1](http://www.nhl.com/ice/page.htm?id=26356) Diving / Embellishment.

Also, if you haven't watched the first link I posted, please do. It's pretty pathetic... haha.

Comment: Your question is duplicate to previous question that was asked here and I advise you to look in my answer - http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1010/what-actions-are-taken-by-fifa-uefa-against-whats-known-as-filming-or-diving/1011#1011

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.. if the Player try to take advantage of it, it usually penalized with a yellow card. Usually there is no foul involved, so the flow of the game goes on.

It is considered unsportman behavior.